# Multiple navigation controllers and back button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a simple question regarding Navigation Controllers and how the back button works.

I have a storyboard as follows:

```
Navigation Controller --> 
        (A)TableController --click on cell--> 
                (B)TabBarController (2 tabs) -->
                      Navigation Controller --> 
                                (C)TableController -->
                                     (D)TableController.
```

My problem is that when i click on the back button at (D) it goes back to point (A).

I want D to go back to A - i.e make the back buttons go back to the previous screen and not what seems to be the root.

Thanks

Comment: did you get a solution to this? I am facing same situation with same hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do something like this;

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The '**self**' here catches the root navigationController. And it's logical that you go back to root (A) because you have one pushed controller from (A).
You need to send popViewControllerAnimated to the UINavigationController in the first tab.

AE;

```
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[nav popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: i am not doing any coding at all at this point simply using the storyboard designer. My understanding is that the navigation controllers are aware of each other?

Comment: Not within this hierarchy